Filtering Google API responses using FieldMasks with Java SDK
I'm using Google's Java SDK to call into DocumentAI service. The response happens to contain the image for each page, in base64, and I'd like to filter that out. During the request building for doing batch processing with the google service, I can configure the DocumentOutputConfig response with some FieldMasks but I can't seem to find a way to filter out a field. I don't want to write a huge list of fields to opt-in, I just to opt-out of a specific field (in this case pages.image.content).
Is this even possible with the Java/Any SDK?

It's not possible via the API and so unlikely to be included as part of an SDK.
FieldMask represents a projection these are commonly explicitly inclusive
One challenge with the projection approach is that, by defining a specific set of fields, the projection doesn't automatically include newly-added fields. Using your proposed exclusion (everything but) approach would include newly-added fields.
As you infer, you will need to fully enumerate the list of fields that you want.
One consideration: do you really need every field except pages.image.content? If not, you could define a more restrictive query that gets a manageable subset of the fields.
Another consideration: Google is diligent in publishing schema for its services (viz. googleapis). You could write a parser (a protoc plugin?) that generates FieldMask's for you with a list of exclusions.

Yes only one field is to be removed since it's a massive field, the rest are fine. The whole point was to avoid to parse stuff schemas and protos. Removing a few fields doesn't seem like a stretch to me, looks like another scenario where anything beyond the basics is offloaded to the user of the SDK.
